# Javascript - Changing Text in Drop Down

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have the following code, which produces a dropdown menu / selector. When one choice is selected, the main display changes to that choice. Although, I'm unable to edit the actual code, I'm able to use this JQuery to edit the text.

```
<fieldset class='topic'> 
<div class='style_picker validatable translate'> 
<label class='topic_style' for='style'> 
Select a topic type:
</label> 
<div class='validatable' id='style_picker'> 
<div class='selector'> 
<span class='selection'></span> 
<span class='handle'></span> 
</div> 
<ul type='none'> 
<li class='ice'> 
<span class='style_item'></span> 
<span class='copy'> 
ice
</span> 
</li> 
<li class='earth'> 
<span class='style_item'></span> 
<span class='copy'> 
earth
</span> 
</li> 
<li class='wind'> 
<span class='style_item'></span> 
<span class='copy'> 
wind
</span> 
</li> 
<li class='fire'> 
<span class='style_item'></span> 
<span class='copy'> 
fire
</span> 
</li> 
<li class='water'> 
<span class='style_item'></span> 
<span class='copy'> 
water
</span> 
</li> 
</ul> 
</div>
```

I've been able to edit the individual choices, but for each edited piece, if selected, the main display still shows the original text, rather than the modified text. For example:

```
    (function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.topic .style_picker li.fire span.copy').text("time");
    });
    })(jQuery);
```

I'm trying to change "fire" to "time". If I use the above code, the selection changes, but the main display stays as "fire". Can anyone offer insight on how to fix this or what I should do? I'm thinking the line responsible is

```
<span class='selection'></span>
```

but I'm not sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are not properly closing your '}' in your ready function. Change it to:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.topic .style_picker li.fire span.copy').text("time");
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I fixed that - it's actually larger in the code, and I just chopped it down. That error isn't my question though... it's not that it's not working - I have no idea how to get it to work. The part that the code changes, and the part I want to change, isn't the same... The code changes the menu text, but not the main display. Do you know how to get that to appear?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hy5rn/ something else must be wrong, because it works in the jsfiddle